# Question about automobile

Tags: riddle

> What is coming with a car, going with a car, there is no purpose in the car, but the car can not do without it?

Comment: If you didn't come up with the riddle, would you be able to cite where you found it?

Comment: @Joe-You-Know I've found it in kids' magazine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2nd Attempt** (Probably wrong but worth a shot)

Is the answer

> Sound, specifically the static noises that come with running a car?

What is coming with a car,

> Sounds that the engine makes, the alternator, etc.

going with a car,

> When a car goes by, it makes the vroom sound.

there is no purpose in the car,

> The sounds a car makes (besides the horn) serve no function, but they do sound cool.

but the car can not do without it?

> While this answer fits the first three pretty well, the last line, I have a problem believing. Electric cars don't really make noise, do they? And saying a car can't do without noise would be a stretch IMHO, except for the horn, which in that case, would serve a purpose. This is why I like my first answer better.

Comment: This was my guess too. I'd say it is the most reasonable answer given here at least.

Comment: Yes!Bravo!You did it!(I was sleeping.)

Answer (score 2):

How about a

> Road

Since

> A car is always seen on a road, but the road does not need the car.

Comment: And, $\ast$ (ROT13) vg unf ab checbfr va gur pne, rvgure $\ast$ Great answer! $(+1)$ :D

Answer (score 1):

The answer of course is

> A human being.

What is coming with a car

> Humans have to purchase a car.

Going with a car

> Are sold to humans

There is no purpose in the car

> Besides traveling.

But the car can not do without it

> The car can't go anywhere without a human (sans google auto cars).

Comment: No.It's not right answer.

Comment: @hahaboki, Really? Wow, I thought I had it for sure.

Comment: And I thought it when I heard it for first time.

Answer (score 0):

I think You are...

> WHEEL (Car Wheel)

How?

> It comes with car and because of wheels car moving.

there is no purpose in the car

> SO wheels kept outsode the car

but the car can not do without it?

> Yes, Without wheels car not move an inch.

Comment: "but the car cannot do without it" [not necessarily](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7f1feSjDks), in the future at least :D

Comment: nope,you missed

Answer (score 0):

How about

> Speed (or: 'motion')

because

> Speed (motion) comes and goes with the car, and the car cannot do anything without speed.
>  Also, when a human is inside the car, they don't need to have speed for themselves, they can just sit back and relax, because the car is doing the work for them. So there is no purpose of having speed when you're inside the car.

Comment: You missed.Try again